# how do i retrieve a session object(stored by servlet) in a jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Is it possible to retrieve session object stored by a servlet, in a JSP file? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EL `${}` in JSP to access objects in page, request, session and application scope by their attribute name. You just have to specify the same name as you used in the servlet to store the attribute. For example, when you store an `User` object with the attribute name `"user"` as follows

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
```

then it's available in the forwarded JSP by the same attribute name as follows

```
${user}
```

Another example if it has a `name` property with a getter:

```xml
<p>Welcome, <c:out value="${user.name}" /></p>
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 0):

What handles the JSP? Anyway, if you use any more or less decent version of EL, you should be able to get it from EL via the implicit `session` object, like `${session.objectName}`.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674197/how-do-i-share-data-between-a-jsp-page-and-servlet) gives a rather comprehensive explanation of session access from JSPs and servlets.

Comment: That's more appropriate as an "possible duplicate" close comment than as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Via EL: `${sessionScope.myObject}`