# How to share data between a JSP and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a website with servlets and JSP.I want to know how to share data between a servlet and JSP as while searching I noticed that the getSession() method has been deprecated and currently I cannot add data to session for sharing the data.Please someone suggest me how should I share data between the servlets and JSP.

Comment: *the getSession() method has been deprecated*. [This is not true](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession--). So either you looked up the wrong documentation, or someone on the internet has lied without posting any reference links and you haven't looked up the documentation to confirm for yourself, or your understanding of the meaning of "deprecated" is wrong.

Comment: Ok I might have used up wrong resource thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply two ways most probably

1 ) request
2 ) session

**Examples :**

```
request.setAttribute("userName", userName );
session.setAttribute("userName", userName );
```

Comment: this is more way good and now i am able to set attributes as per the requirements.Thank you for helping me

Comment: @vedantGandhi try to keep post the question by follow some protocals refer this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: ok sorry sir i will try not to do it again

Comment: We live we learn -- follow this.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the below references.This will help ful to you

[how-do-i-share-data-between-a-jsp-page-and-servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674197/how-do-i-share-data-between-a-jsp-page-and-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

in your body method `doGet` do something like that,

```
String value = "par1"
request.setAttribute("parameter", value);
```

your jsp file:

```
<%
 String value= (String) request.getAttribute("parameter");
 out.println(value);
 %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.It has worked