# How to share result data between servlet and display on jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've gone through similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518878/how-to-share-data-between-a-jsp-and-servlet) on this site and still in doubt with it.

I have a basic calculation on one servlet call `add servlet` and want to get user input to show the total on the same JSP page via another servlet called `view total servlet` (a table view).

E.g. `addServlet` on doGet

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("add"));

        int subTotal = 10 + i;

        System.out.println("subtotal is (servlet) = " + subTotal);

        // session mgmt to share data
        request.setAttribute("subTotal", subTotal);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("view_total");
        rd.forward(request, response);


The `view total servlet` on doGet

// get input from add servlet
        int subTotal = (int) request.getAttribute("subTotal");
        subTotal = 0 * subTotal;

        String viewTotal = "frontend/view_total.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(viewTotal);
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

The JSP

```
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>$10</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="add" /></td> `// get user input`
                <td> ${ subTotal } /td> `// how to show total value here`
            </tr>
```

Comment: Hi , what doesn't work in your current code ? Also , you need to set that `subTotal` value in request attribute and access same at jsp using `EL` i.e `${yourattributename}` or `<%=  request.getAttribute("yourattributename")%>` .Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898393/how-to-access-a-request-attribute-set-by-a-servlet-in-jsp) post .

Comment: But `int subTotal = (int) request.getAttribute("subTotal");` is NPE even I put ${ subTotal } in the <td> tag.

Comment: You have added servlet code of two different servlet or both are same ? Please remove irrelevant code .

Comment: @Swati - I want to separate into two servlets so I can understand how it works. Besides, can it be done in one servlet, let said only put to `view_total servlet`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is any value in `session` if yes then get that value and add new with old one and then set new `subTotal` again else just add the value which is there in `i` in your session .So your code will somewhat look like below  :

```
String viewTotal = "frontend/view_total.jsp";
int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("add"));
int subTotal,
newvalue;
//check if there is value in session
if (request.getAttribute("subTotal") != null) {
  //get that
  subTotal = (int) request.getAttribute("subTotal");
  //add new value to subtotal not sure why you add 10..make change according to your requirements
  newvalue = subTotal + i;
  //set it again with new total
  request.setAttribute("subTotal", newvalue);
}
else {
  //set the value which user sends
  request.setAttribute("subTotal", i + 10);
}

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(viewTotal);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow got `java.lang.NumberFormatException` on the line where  `getParameter("add") `...

Comment: Are you sure `add` is not null . Put that code around `if(request.getParameter("add") != null ){ // get that thing here }` .Also , this is just demo code you need to modify according to your requirement :)

Comment: Thanks for help! May I ask are you done it all in one servlet or using two servlets to share input data?

Comment: I have use only one servlet here has changes need to make in `subTotal` only .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm lost how to get user input and show it on the same JSP page using the dispatcher...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223637/discussion-between-swati-and-stu-dent).